# I'm trying to use AllScripts Practice Management API but get 'action not supported'

Tags: api, integration

I'm using [UnityHelloWorldPython](https://developer.allscripts.com/files/Code%20Samples/UnityHelloWorldPython.zip) example. I've setup credentials from my test application and get token successfully. Service url is `http://propmga-azure.unitysandbox.com`

From the whole [list of actions](https://developer.allscripts.com/APIReference/ActionList?product=8be8f3c6-6f59-4973-aecf-dde0cd03955e) only `GetPatient` and `SearchPatients` seems to work. All other I tried return errors:

```
[
    {
        "Error": "Magic Error - Action: GetScheduleByPatientID - action 'GetScheduleByPatientID' is not supported."
    }
]
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Are you using your production or your testing credentials?

Comment: I used testing credential. The was issue of using wrong endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

ADP's licensing works in this way: for testing, you can make any call you want. For production, you can only make the calls that you have been "licensed" to call. When you go through your [Certification](https://developer.allscripts.com/Home/howitworks), you'll be licensed to make the API calls that you used during your certification exercise.

So you need to make sure you are using only those calls for which you are licensed when you are contacting a production system or you will get this error you have above.

My recommendation would be to have some calls in your application that run at start up, just to get you "credit" for having made those calls, so you can call them in production. Very helpful calls to have include `GetListOfDictionaries` and `GetDictionary` which can help you find information when your client is having trouble doing it via the traditional user interface for the product. (Those two calls are for the EHR products... I'm not sure how relevant they are for the PM product.)

Comment: Good advice. Thank you